# What is the Role of Magento Compilation from Admin?

Tags: performance, magento, pagespeed

I want to speed by my Magneto site.I got the solution from stackoverflow and from Google.There is a process call "Compilation process".

Can some one please explain what is the internal process after enable compilation from the Magneto Admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

When compilation is set to on then in Magento all needed files that are in different folders all are copied to an src folder.

This results in reduced PHP execution as PHP does not need to go through many folders.